# What is the most likely sequence?

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability

I have a jar containing `n` numbered marbles, where `1...x` marbles are red and marbles `x+1...n` are black, and I want to remove them one by one. However, red marbles are larger and more likely to be grabbed: at any time, each red marble is `k` times more likely to be selected than each black marble, regardless of the number of marbles left of each type.

For example if we have 2 red and 9 black, the chance to extract "a red marble" is `2k/(2k+9)` and the chance of extracting "a black marble" is `9/(2k+9)` --- but of course for a specific marble `i` this is `k/(2k+9)` if red and `1/(2k+9)` if black. So it could be that selecting "a black marble" is more likely, but if we look at them singularly, red are always more likely to be selected.

If I extract all the marbles, what is the most likely sequence I get, and how likely is it?

My intuition is that the most likely sequence is any of the form `red,red,...,red,black,black,...,black` (all reds in any order, then all blacks in any order), and these are all equally likely.
This is what we get by "greedily" choosing the most likely event at each step, i.e., a red marble if present, but I am not sure as to how it can be proven. Pointers to relevant theory are also appreciated.

Comment: Your guess is correct. Consider two sequences of draws that differ only by, at times $t$ and $t+1$, replacing "black red" by "red black". I will show that the second is more likely. Using this repeatedly, all reds before all blacks is the most likely.

Comment: Since the sequences agree up to time $t-1$, the probability of reaching that stage, and since they agree after time $t+2$ (with the same number of balls in the bucket), the probability of the events after that stage are equal. So what remains is just to compute, if there are $r$ red balls and $b$ black balls at time $t$, whether it is more likely to draw red first or black first, followed by the other color second.

Comment: The odds of "red then black" are $\tfrac{r k}{r k +b} \tfrac{b}{(r-1)k+b}$, the odds of black then red are $\tfrac{b}{r k +b} \tfrac{r k}{rk+(b-1)}$. Since $k>1$, we have $(r-1)k+b < rk+(b-1)$, and all the other factors are equal, so $\tfrac{r k}{r k +b} \tfrac{b}{(r-1)k+b} > \tfrac{b}{r k +b} \tfrac{r k}{rk+(b-1)}$.

Comment: This really is more of a math stackexchange question, but I don't feel like going through the shuffle of waiting for enough relocation votes to put up the answer. It is certainly possible for an elementary combinatorial question to belong on MO, but it is a good guess that, if your question has no material beyond undergrad, and if you are not a person who usually solves graduate exercises easily (so that you can know that this is more difficult than those), your question probably belongs on math.SE .

Comment: Thanks David! Indeed the proof is remarkably easy, should have probably figured that out. If you feel like posting this as an answer I will accept it, otherwise I can just delete the question if you think its best.

Comment: I put in an answer, so you can accept this and remove it from the unanswered list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is to note that I answered the question in the comments.